# rails how get related id on view page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm trying to make this conditional:

```
<% if current_boutique.boutique_kind(3) %>
  Brand: <span><%= current_boutique.name %></span>

  <% else %>
<%= p.input :brand_id, :as => :select, :collection=> Brand.find(:all, :order=>:name).collect{ |b| [b.name,b.id,  b.name]},
  :label => "Marca", :prompt => 'Select Brand', :required => true  %>

<% end %>
```

but the `boutique_kind(3)` show all boutiques! how i just get the boutiques with boutiques_kind id 3 method!

boutiqueKind Controller

```
def show 
  @boutique_kind = BoutiqueKind.find(params[:id])
end
```

boutiqueKind model

```
 attr_accessible :kind, :slug

  has_many                      :boutiques
  has_many                      :products, :through => :boutiques
  #belongs_to                    :gender
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :boutiques
  attr_accessible               :boutiques, :boutiques_attributes, :kind
```

Boutique Controller

```
class Boutique < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :boutique_kind
end
```

Comment: can you show the body of the method `boutique_kind` ?

Comment: right, the method on the controller or on model?

Comment: Why are you asking me? It is your code.. Lollz :)

Comment: yeah, but you said body of the method! so asked which one! because for this boutique_kind i have on model and on controller

Comment: Give us all.. we will check then..what is wrong.

Comment: Not sure if your last edit to the question was meant to include the `boutique_kind` method (since it came after your last comment). Anyway, you are calling the method on `current_boutique`, which I imagine is a method returning a model...

Comment: Uhm... no, that is __not__ the `boutique_kind` method. As for the model, we will need the class declaration too.

Comment: tompave the class declaration i wrote alrady on the question, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the boutique by ID with:

```
BoutiqueKind.find(3)
```

If I'm misunderstanding, and id is not a unique id (in which case I suggest you rename the column to something other than id), you can get all records where a certain field == a specific value with:

```
BoutiqueKind.where(id: 3)
```

Comment: `BoutiqueKind.where(id: 3).first`

Comment: but can i add this method on the view page?

Comment: You *can*, but it breaks the MVC rules. Better to put it in your controller and assign it a variable name, then reference that variable in your view.

Comment: If it worked, would you mind clicking the checkmark on my answer? That's the bit of cheese for us mice.